# TypeError updating a nested array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

I was hoping to be able to update a state object from this:

```
this.state = {
          items: {},
}
```

to this:

```
this.state = {
          items: {
              2020-01-01: [
                     {'text': 'Some text', 'start_time': 'Some time'},
                     {'text': 'Some text', 'start_time': 'Some time'}],
              2020-01-02: [
                     {'text': 'Some text', 'start_time': 'Some time'},
                     {'text': 'Some text', 'start_time': 'Some time'}]
          }
}
```

by using spread operator:

```
//response from the API
response.items.map((item, index) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
           items: {
             ...prevState.items,
             [item.time]: [
               ...prevState.items[item.time], 
               {
                'text': item.summary,
                'start_time': item.start_time
               }]
           }
  }))
});
```

but that generates a TypeError:

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

The purpose of updating the state object in such way is to render [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#agenda) component with data pulled from an API. But I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: seems not clear, why not first loop and create the object first or use `Array.reduce`, and once object built, you set the state to avoid inconsistencies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter what `time` is in the `.map`, it does not exist as a property of `items` in the initial state, the first time this code is run:

```js
const initialState = {
  items: {},
};

const time = '2020-01-01';
const newState = ({
  items: {
    ...initialState.items,
    [time]: [
      ...initialState.items[time],
      {
        'text': item.summary,
        'start_time': item.start_time
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Alternate with the empty array instead, so that it can be spread properly:

```
...(initialState.items[time] || []),
```

```js
const initialState = {
  items: {},
};

const item = { summary: 'foo', start_time: 'bar' };

const time = '2020-01-01';
const newState = ({
  items: {
    ...initialState.items,
    [time]: [
      ...(initialState.items[time] || []),
      {
        'text': item.summary,
        'start_time': item.start_time
      }
    ]
  }
});
console.log(newState);
```